# calculating float type average with for loop C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to get an float type average number from int inputs using the for loop.
But it doesn't show me a correct answer.
Could anyone tell me what i have done wrong?
I think probably I made mistakes in this part,

```
for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
{
    sum =+ myArray[ i ];
}
return static_cast< float >( sum ) / size;
```

I have attached picture so you can see the whole code.

[image: code picture]

Thank you for any advices

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: I was trying to reproduce your issue by pasting your code into my IDE.  My IDE doesn't understand pictures.  Please post your code as text.  No code posted as text == no help.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
sum =+ myArray[ i ];
```

will apply unary`+` on right hand side value and then assign that to `sum`, which is not what you want.

You're looking for:

```
sum += myArray[ i ];
```

which will add the right hand side to `sum`.

Comment: This should just be closed as a typo

Comment: @Barmar Ok, sounds good to me.